# stoping the SwipeMenuLIstView to Swipe

Tags: android

i am using Swipe menu list View from the Githu
https://github.com/baoyongzhang/SwipeMenuListView

According to my project requirement i need to stop some list View to Swipe
for example i want to stop the list item on the postion 5
how i would do that

```
mListView.setOnSwipeListener(new SwipeMenuListView.OnSwipeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSwipeStart(int position) {
            if (positon == 5) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "you are not Allow to Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwipeEnd(int position) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a private instance of the listener and than set it to the mListView if a condition is met and if you want to not allow the swiping to be active you can simply set the onSwipeListener to null like this:

```
private SwipeMenuListView.OnSwipeListener swipeListener = new     SwipeMenuListView.OnSwipeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSwipeStart(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSwipeEnd(int i) {

    }
});
if (condtion) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "you are not Allow to    Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           //disable swiping
           mListView.setOnSwipeListener(null);

        }else{
          //allow swiping
          mListView.setOnSwipeListener(swipeListener);
        }
```

Comment: But i want to stop the Swipe for some items in the list View not all items means the item at the position 5 will not be swipe able but all other can. In this Way how i can get the position of the item

Comment: i have made changing in my  question

Answer (score 0):

you can use BaseSwipListAdapter and change condition according your requirments.

```
 @Override
public boolean getSwipEnableByPosition(int position) {
    if(position==5){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```